# Better approach to making groups of entries by some attribute in Laravel and returning them

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, eloquent

I'm making some API in Laravel and I would like to return JSON response like that:

```
{
    "attribValue1": [entries],
    "attribValue2": [entries],
    "attribValue3": [entries]
}
```

so I've made these requests on database:

```
$attribValue1 = Partner::where([['partner_type', '=', 'attribValue1'], ['enabled', '=', true]])->orderBy('position', 'asc')->get();
$attribValue2 = Partner::where([['partner_type', '=', 'attribValue2'], ['enabled', '=', true]])->orderBy('position', 'asc')->get();
$attribValue3 = Partner::where([['partner_type', '=', 'attribValue3'], ['enabled', '=', true]])->orderBy('position', 'asc')->get();

return compact('attribValue1', 'attribValue2', 'attribValue3');
```

But my problem is that I don't like this solution. It queries database three times, so I'm finding better solution. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
$attribs = Partner::where('enabled', true)
    ->whereIn('partner_type', ['attribValue1', 'attribValue2', 'attribValue3'])
    ->orderBy('position', 'asc')
    ->get()
    ->groupBy('partner_type');

dd($attribs->toArray()); // Show what you get.
```

Now, you have three collections grouped by attributes. So it's it's easy to convert it to JSON. More information about `groupBy` on collections here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-groupby

Comment: nice, I had `groupBy()` before `get()` and it didn't work, but your solution is right :)

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$attribs = Partner::where('enabled', true)
    ->whereIn('partner_type', ['attribValue1', 'attribValue2', 'attribValue3'])
    ->orderBy('position', 'asc')
    ->get()->groupBy('partner_type');
`dd($attribs)`;
```

And then use the data accordingly.

Comment: My problem is not that I'm not getting the right response ... I don't like three database queries